Else clause of ifelse() not executing
In this MRE, I want to create a third group called age_group, and for all remaining values that do not meet the conditions, to be the actual age. Even if I make age a string ('age'), the age_group variable does not replace these values with "age". What's going on here?
new_df = df%>%
  mutate(age_group = ifelse(
             age %in% c(0:35), '0 to 35 years', ifelse(
               age_options=='-66', 'Prefer not to answer', ifelse(
                 age_options =='-99', 'Missing', age))
             )
           )

data
df = structure(list(age = c(NA, NA, 38, 33, 35, 44, 33, 26, 51, 42
), age_options = c(-99, -99, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                             -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


This is a perfect use case to use dplyr::case_when instead, which is clearer than nested ifelse's.

Thanks, Jon, I actually was using case_match for creating the age categories (there are more than just 0:35, but then used if else to include age_options column and I thought case_match only took in one vector.  I will look through the documentation, now, in more depth, but shouldn't this ifelse statement be working?

You could add is.na(age_options), age, ifelse( after your age %in% line -- you need to deal with na's first since testing age_options == '-66' on na will output NA.

Ah--thanks so much! And also, yes, case_when() got me exactly what I needed! I've been incorporating case_match()...good to see how case_when() can also be used!

all you needed to do is change the == to %in%, you dont need to test for na or anything

When you test age_options == '-66' on NA input in ifelse, the output is NA, instead of FALSE, so it doesn't send us to the following test(s). So you could deal with NA's in the age_options variable first, e.g.
df%>%
  mutate(age_group = ifelse(
    age %in% c(0:35), '0 to 35 years', ifelse(
      is.na(age_options), age, ifelse(
        age_options=='-66', 'Prefer not to answer', ifelse(
          age_options =='-99', 'Missing', age)))))

(As @rawr suggested in the comments, another option could be to use age_options %in% '-66' instead of == '-66'; this will evaluate FALSE with NA, avoiding the problem here.)
In any case, this logic would be clearer using case_when, which is cleaner to read and doesn't have  the same issue with propagating test NAs: case_when gives the specified output when the test is TRUE, instead of when it is TRUE or NA. One adjustment, though, is that with if_else or case_when, we need to intentionally coerce the output types to be consistent, i.e. all character. See here.
df%>%
  mutate(age_group = case_when(
    age %in% c(0:35) ~ '0 to 35 years',
    age_options=='-66' ~ 'Prefer not to answer',
    age_options=='-99' ~ 'Missing',
    .default = as.character(age)))

     age age_options age_group    
   <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>        
 1    NA         -99 Missing      
 2    NA         -99 Missing      
 3    38          NA 38           
 4    33          NA 0 to 35 years
 5    35          NA 0 to 35 years
 6    44          NA 44           
 7    33          NA 0 to 35 years
 8    26          NA 0 to 35 years
 9    51          NA 51           
10    42          NA 42


Yeah, after you suggested case_when I looked at the documentation and implemented that, and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Thanks for the explanation regarding NA as well!

Quick follow-up. I have a few edge cases like 7.5 that aren't being included in the c(0:15) vector. I tried coercing to double (after reading this), but that still isn't working. I added both mutate(age = as.double(age)) and an as.double(c(0:15)) but didn't work. How do I solve this?

%in% c(0:35) or %in% 0:35 tests if something matches the integers from 0 to 35 or characters that look like them. You might want instead age >= 0 & age <= 35 or age |> between(0,35)

Like JonSpring stated, use dplyr::case_when(). It works out a lot better than ifelse() does in R.
It would look like this switched over from the ifelse():
new_df = df%>%
  mutate(age_group = case_when(
                       age %in% c(0:35) ~ '0 to 35 years',
                       age_options=='-66' ~ 'Prefer not to answer',
                       age_options=='-99' ~ 'Missing'
                       .default = age
             )
           )

